# connecting Access DB to VS using C#

Tags: c#, database

This is the 1st time I am using C# connection with db, also I dont use access.
I just want to know the initial steps required to connect the access db to visual studio C# windows application.
I have searched though the internet, It helped a lot. I cant find my mistake in the code. I think I am missing some steps in establishing the connection with the db.

here is the error that appears when I try to run the program "'\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."

CODE:

```
OleDbConnection bookConn;
OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand();

String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= \\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101; Persist Security Info=False";

    public Form1()
    {
        bookConn = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bookConn.Open(); //*ERROR LINE
        oleDbCmd.Connection = bookConn;


        bookConn.Close();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add `.mdb` after database name or `.accdb` if you are using `Microsoft Office Access 2007` or higher database but, for that you have to change Provider also.

```
String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= \\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101.mdb; Persist Security Info=False";
```

Or you can use connection string like this

```
String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
```

**EDITED:**

for ACCESS 2010

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101.accdb"
```

Comment: Jet.OLEDB.4.0 cannot open an .accdb file

Comment: then it must be `.mdb`

Comment: @random still having problem? what error is displaying?

Comment: can there be an issue because of the saving the database?? in tutorial it said to save it with some extension *.*. I couldn't get what they meant.

Comment: this is the error that appears "'\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."

Comment: you have to add extension of the database after database path ie. ..\Database101.mdb

Comment: u have to use provider `OLEDB.12.0` for that.. i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First your file name does not have the file extension name like `.mdb`

```
 Database101\MyDB.mdb
```

Second, if it is in a network. Would it be better if you `net use` first in you DOS prompt to assign a drive letter for your network, like:

```
 net use z: \\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\AAA\Database101 your_password /USER:your_account
```

Then your connection string will be shorter then:

```
 String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= z:\MyDB.mdb; Persist Security Info=False";
```

If the file extension by the way is `.accdb` instead of `.mdb` it should be:

```
 String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=z:\MyDB.mdb;;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Or simply your path is simply wrong.

Go to windows explorer and just clink on the path where your file is and copy paste it.

Comment: if the `f38910` is Network pc then it must be started with \\.

Comment: My senior gave me an example code in visual basic and there the code worked fine ...  :Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =\\f38910\Users\kainat.baig\Desktop\RFA_DB.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;;")